# Does cubical canonicity imply closed version of regularity?

Tags: cubical-type-theory, canonicity, regularity

Clarification of my terminologies:

- Cubical canonicity: a generalized version of canonicity that the "generated by introduction rules" property holds in, not just closed context, but also contexts with only intervals.
- Regularity: the fact that transport over a constant path reduces to the identity function.

Some work (`\cite{CarloThesis}`) has shown that regularity does not hold in general. However, cubical canonicity should imply that: in a closed context, any path is convertible to a constant path. Hence we can probably guarantee that closed paths are reflexive paths. So, do regularity hold in closed contexts? Can we assume closed regularity in compiled cubical code?

Comment: Can you make the statement of cubical canonicity more precise ? I thought that only homotopy canonicity (canonicity up to a path rather than definitional equality) could be proved for cubical type theories...

Comment: @kyodralliam basically as described in the abstract here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04156

Comment: Note that that result only explicitly states canonicity for $ℕ$. Usually I see experts state that regularity fails to hold for the universe, but holds in general for many types, e.g. $ℕ$. So, I thought an obvious example to try is something like $\mathsf{transport}\ \mathsf{refl}\ ℕ$. However, at least cubical Agda says this is judgmentally equal to $ℕ$, so this case of regularity holds as well. If it does fail for some closed term, I'm unsure how to write one (unless Agda is wrong here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by:

> However, cubical canonicity should imply that: in a closed context, any path is convertible to a constant path.

It's definitely not correct if the type in question is not hSet, or I misunderstand your claim. As far as I know, at least in [CHM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01170.pdf) (and also in Cubical Agda), the operation `hcomp` is somewhat freely defined for general HITs. That means `hcomp` cannot be reduced whatever you put in its arguments. But it's still possible that any paths and even higher cubes in empty context are compositions of `hcomp` and the constructors. However, for ordinary inductive type, namely it does not involve any path constructors, your claim about canonicity is probably true, because basically you cannot define any paths other than `refl` and now `hcomp` can reduce. Try ℕ in Cubical Agda. But I'm not sure if anyone has done a proof.

I don't know much about other cubical theory. In [CCHM](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01378906/document), The operation `transp` (as a special case, `transport`) is defined inductively, as you may already know. For most type constructors, it reduces to `transp` in simpler types. For universe, it's just constant. For HITs, it is defined recursively for constructors. So if the construction of your type only involves these stuffs, regularity holds for it in the empty context. But it's incorrect for `Glue` type (and also for `hcomp` in universe) of which definition needs complicated correction of boundaries. No regularity should be expected in this case.

Comment: What is an example of a closed term that behaves irregularly, though? I even tried `transp (λ j → notEq (i ∧ j)) (~ i) false` to get a term of type `(i : I) → notEq i`. `notEq i` reduces to $\sf Glue$. Agda accepts the reflexive proof of: `∀ i → transport (λ k → notEq i) (b i) ≡ b i`, so this example is regular, too, and it's not even closed with respect to the cubical context. Is this a bug?

Comment: I think hcomp in universe reduces to Glue (if you do have Glue)

Comment: @DanDoel The `transp` for `Glue` type results in a mixture of function application (by the corresponding equivalence) and `hcomp` (for boundary correction). So if you want irregular term, the boundary correction should really happen (it can be trivial in some cases) and `hcomp` for that type should not reduce, like a general HIT as I've mentioned. Type `Bool` is an ordinary inductive type. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @DanDoel As an example, consider a path defined by `p i = Glue S¹ (λ { (i = i0) → (S¹ , idEquiv _) })`, of which type is `S¹ ≡ Glue S¹ empty`. You will find `transport (p ∙ sym p) base` reduces to `hcomp (λ i → empty) base` and it isn't definitionally equal to `base`!

Comment: @ice1000 It's right in that paper. But in Cubical Agda, `hcomp` for universe is defined primitively and the rules are mimicking `Glue`. IIRC, it's called `HCompU` in its implementation.

Comment: Does this mean that closed terms `transport refl t` (for, _literally_ `refl`) are _always_ judgmentally equal to `t`? And the closed irregular terms are essentially `hcomp {φ = i0} (λ k ()) t`? And whether `transport P t` is irregular depends on whether `P` causes it to reduce to the `hcomp` expression (by composition through the empty system) even though `P` might otherwise be expected to be equal to `refl`?

Comment: No. The problem is still at `Glue` type. An example is, let `b = glue empty base` of type `Glue S¹ empty`, the term `transport refl b` is a complicated composition of `hcomp`, and is not `b`.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I see. `refl` for `Glue T empty` is itself something that causes `transport` to turn into the empty `hcomp`.

Comment: There are also terms like `hcomp (λ i → empty) (hcomp (λ i → empty) (hcomp (λ i → empty x)))`, and you can do this no matter how many times. For `Glue` types, I think you should not anticipate `transport refl (glue ...)` is exactly the same as `glue ...` in general.